# How do I disable the Submit button until the input fields conditions are met?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need the submit button to be disabled until all the form fields are filled. I have done the following in HTML file:

```
<button dlsButton class="pt-primary adconfig-button" (click)="testConnection()" 
[disabled]="!adForm.form.valid" i18n>Test Connection</button>
```

and this in TS file:

```
this.adForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        DnsDomain: ['', [Validators.required], [Validators.minLength(1)]],
        UserName: ['', [Validators.required], [Validators.minLength(1)]],
        Password: ['', [Validators.required], [Validators.minLength(1)]],
    });
```

how can I make the button disabled it is still enable now

Answer (score 1):

change `[disabled]="!adForm.form.valid"` to `[disabled]="!adForm.valid"`

Comment: This should work. @SiddharthGautam have you verified if your custom validation isn't creating any error? Try printing each field errors and check